# Notify client with updated Records-Asp.net

Tags: signalr

I want to create app in asp.net ( may be signalR or web API)

Here is a case

1) 3rd party or external application update xml file ( around 1000 entries) on each 15 minutes on Server

2) XML contains ProdID,Qty,ShippingDate

3) with ProdID, name and description of product is retrieved from database.

4) On UI, Readonly view need to display for all records from XML in tabular format.

5) when any records change on server side ( XML is overwritten on 15 minutes),change color for products which Qty or ShippingDate is updated also send new value of qty and shippingdate
6) in rare case, records may be deleted in xml ( product is removed in new version of xml)


I m thinking on following design

- Cache XML in asp.net app and update cache on change of that xml
- use linq to convert xml to collection of class
- store previous collectioin and current collection when cache is cleared
- compare collection and identify which records are changed
- prepare collection of changed records which can be retried with public method on server.
- Send notification to client that records on server updated.
  on client, on notification make call to server to get data.

let me know how/which is faster way to compare collection of xml to identify which records are changed.

method to get xml data from server to client is done by web API

how web API and Signal R can be in same app. I new to SignalR

any input will be great on this approach

Answer (score 0):

1. Your fasted search is going to be using Dictionary<[Id], [Class]>
2. If you don't understand how to use WebApi, that might be something you want to look into.
3. You don't need to use WebApi if you are using signalR, but If you are adding to an existing application then I would suggest using the WebApi to do the bulk of the heavy lifting for data, You can specify mime-type in the header application/xml data and let the client handle it.
4. Use signalr to broadcast your change delta to multiple clients, so that you are only working with the changed data in the live updates.